# null pointer exception in GeoPoint on android

Tags: java, android

in my app i am storing latitude and longitude in a List as GeoPoint as follows:

`List<GeoPoint>geo;`

here i convert latitude and longitude into GeoPoint and store in list.

```
GeoPoint tmp;

new GeoPoint((int) ( 9.909228086471558 * 1E6), (int) ( 78.10081958770752 * 1E6)); 
geo.add(tmp); // i get null pointer exception . Line no:42
```

Logcat

```
  05-30 18:33:25.203: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  05-30 18:33:25.203: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6363):     at net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.main.onCreate(main.java:42)
  05-30 18:33:25.203: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6363):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1132)
  05-30 18:33:25.203: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
```

how to clear the null pointer exception. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

```
// if you don't do this, it could cause your NPE
List<GeoPoint>geo = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
```

Also, this looks better this way:

```
GeoPoint tmp = new GeoPoint((int) ( 9.909228086471558 * 1E6), (int) ( 78.10081958770752 * 1E6)); 
geo.add(tmp);
```

Instead of using `.iterator()` this is recomended:

```
for(GeoPoint point : geo){
    // use the `point` object as you would in a interator
}
```

Comment: i use your answer i get java.util.NoSuchElementException at 
     Iterator<GeoPoint> itr = geo.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()){
             p= itr.next(); // here the exception
            }